# Making inline controls in jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am generating a collapsible set dynamically in which I have a text box and search button for the Search purpose.

I am looping through the result of a method and binding dynamically generated collapsible set to a div . My problem came up with the Search part alignment only

I am getting space between the Search text box and Buttons when i viewed in larger screen mobiles, And button is wrapping below the text box when i viewed it in smaller screen mobiles.

My code is:

```
var FillHis = '<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b" id="set" data-iconpos="right"  class="ag_nomargin" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">';
                    FillHis += '<div class="ui-field-contain ag_noborder" style="padding-top:0px !important;padding-bottom:5px !important;">';
       FillHis += '<div  style="width:57%;float: left;position:relative; margin: -5px 0px 0px 1px;"> <input type="search"  name="search" id="txtSearchDrug" placeholder="Search drug"></div> ';
       FillHis += '<div style="width:42; float: right;position:relative; margin: -1px 0px 0px 0px;"><a id="A13" style="height:14px;line-height:12px;padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px;float:right" onclick="LoadFillHistory();" href="#"  > Show All</a>  <a id="A12" style="height:14px;line-height:12px;padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px;float:right"onclick="SearchDrug();" href="#" > Go</a></div></div>';
```

I tried using "controlgroup" and data-type="horizontal" still no use. I just want to make my two buttons fixed size and Textbox will increase with size of the screen. Please can somebody help me . I added screenshots also[image: Larger screens]

[image]

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/x97s3752/ ?

Comment: Thanx for the fiddle.........is there a way to add space between controlgroup items...

Comment: I created an answer with the buttons spaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting the input and buttons in separate DIVs and then applying some CSS.

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b" id="set" data-iconpos="right" class="ag_nomargin" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
         <h4>heading</h4>
         <div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="right"> 
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Show All</a>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Go</a>
                </div>
                <div class="left">
                    <input type="search" name="search" id="txtSearchDrug" placeholder="Search drug" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.container {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
    width: 154px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.right a:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
.right .ui-btn-inner {
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}
.right a:last-child {
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.left {
    float: none;
    /* not needed, just for clarification */
    /* the next props are meant to keep this block independent from the other floated one */
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left .ui-input-search {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

This will work whether the collapsibles are added at design time or dynamically.

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/x97s3752/3/)**